# Opening Sibling Files in Document Based iOS App

Tags: ios, uidocument

I want to have a custom project file that a user selects in a UIDocumentBrowserViewController. That project file would then reference files in the same directory which would be opened and written to programmatically. I can't seem to get access to the project's sibling files programmatically (presumably due to sandbox restrictions). What's the best way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the enclosing folder a document package, i.e. a folder that shows up in the file browser as a single file. I then had access to read all the files in it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html